# How to pass parameter to the function with apply in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have functions, to pass the parameters from `a` to `b`.

but it seems the `apply` just access 2 parameters

```
function a(){
  var p1=1;
  var p2=2;
  b.apply(this,arguments);
}


function b(){
    //so how to get p1,p2 in this function?
    console.log(arguments);
}

a(3,4);
```

so how to pass the `p1`  `p2` in function `a`  and get `1,2,3,4` in function`b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create an array with all the parameters you need to pass:

```
var combinedArray = [p1, p2].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
```

this function:

1. Creates an array with first 2 elements as `p1` and `p2`
2. And appends the arguments array to it.

Then you can call it as `b.apply(this, combinedArray)`

PS:

The `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` is used to convert `arguments` object to a real array.

Comment: Please don't recommend slicing `arguments` like that. See https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#32-leaking-arguments .

Comment: @ralh if it's invoked once - it does not matter. If it's invoked million times - OP would be aware of that.

Comment: @chanjianyi they can be of any type.

Comment: I just consider it bad practice to recommend that, if there's a better way. And I don't see how the OP would be aware of the deoptimization if it was invoked many times. Perhaps he would eventually find out, but you're still giving imperfect advice.

Comment: @ralh what should I have recommended instead? This is never gonna be a problem for something that is not a general purpose high performance library.

Comment: @ralh I do know that article for sure. And I asked you how you would recommend to change my proposed solution to still keep it reasonable complicated as per constraints and requirements? If you are ready to provide a "better" answer - please do so.

Comment: how about if `var p1=function(){return 1;  };` , how to get the `1` in `b`? XD

Comment: @chanjianyi if it's a function - just invoke it. `var one = arguments[0]();` http://jsfiddle.net/mccqjpjc/

Comment: @zerkms hi, one more question XD, how to remove the `p1` in `b()`, I've tried `var args=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);args.shift();` seems not work.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with demonstration that it does not work

Comment: @zerkms thank you. it is work right now. just need to `apply` the `args` is ok.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass your variables to another function you have to add them to the array you provide to `apply`. But you can not add them directly to the `arguments` variable since it's not the real array. So first of all you have to build a new array which you would pass to `apply`. You can transform `arguments` to array by `var newArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);` - this creates new array from `arguments`. Now you can act with it as with regular array (`newArray.push(p1);` or `newArray = newArray.concat([p1, p2]);` and so on). And then just pass this array to `apply` instead of `arguments`.

So your code would change this way:

```
function a(){
  var p1=1;
  var p2=2;
  var argumentsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  b.apply(this, argumentsArray.concat([p1, p2]));
}


function b(){
    console.log(arguments);
}

a(3,4); // output: [3, 4, 1, 2];
```

If you need to prepend `p1` and `p2` you can use [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
void temp() { 
    var animals = ["cat", "dog", "horse", "cow"];
    animals.forEach(function (eachName, index) {
     console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName); 
    });
}
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?